# I got an error while trying the HTTP Test Script Recorder in Jmeter

Tags: firefox, jmeter

I got an error while I am doing recording at Jmeter. [This is the error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lble.png)
It has given me this error. Would you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The error states that JMeter wasn't able to get the response from the https://demo.yetenekkapisi.org website.

The site works fine for me:

[image]

So it might be something between **your** JMeter and the site

The most common reason is that your machine requires a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) for accessing the Internet and you need to make JMeter aware of this proxy, it can be done by the following [command-line arguments:](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

```
jmeter -H your_proxy_host -P your_proxy_port
```

if it helps you can make the change permanent by adding the next lines to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
http.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
https.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
http.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
https.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
```

More information:

- [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Appriciate for your answer and thanks for helping...

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing? what do you mean by saying your_proxy_host? where can i find it?

Comment: In your browser or operating system proxy settings